# How do I tell whether Ubuntu phone is using 2G or 3G?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, 3g

I have a bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition. There's a signal indicator in the top bar, but I can't see any indication whether it's got a GSM/EDGE/3G signal. How do I find this out?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, in the status bar, you must see **3G**

(Note that your wifi must be disconnect)

Please, check if the tick **2G/3G** (see red dot) is marked at System Settings > Mobile:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to add in an image in english? :)

Comment: Yep... Of course :)

Comment: I only see the "2G only (saves battery)" option on my phone, there's no "2G/3G (faster)" option to select.

Comment: Oops! Maybe your simcard doesn't support this feature. Do you check it in another phone (i.e. with android...)?